# Making koha and dspace available on a network

Tags: networking, command-line, localhost, virtual-console

Recently, I installed Koha on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. I was informed that extensive configuration isn't necessary; I just need to ping the IP. However, I'm unfamiliar with these steps. I'd like to make the IP address of my Koha accessible across all local networks, so that other computers can access it via their browsers when connected to the same network as the Koha server. What are the steps to do that?